# png resampling in php produces black box from "create true color" but doesn't resample - not getting errors

Tags: php, png, resampling

png resampling in php produces black box from "create true color" but doesn't resample - not getting errors...
I have very similar code set up for the JPG version of the function and it works fine... this also shows other things tried (commented out)...

```
function resizeImgPng($fileDesitin8n, $fileNewName){
$percent = 0.34;
$file2Desitin8n = 'UPLOADS/' . 'src' . $fileNewName;

header('Content-Type: image/png');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileDesitin8n);
$newWidth = $width * $percent; 
$newHeight = $height * $percent;
// print_r($width . ' ' . $newWidth . ' ' . $height . ' ' . $newHeight);
// exit();

$profImg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
$srcImg = imagecreatefrompng($fileDesitin8n);

// $bg = imagecolorallocate($profImg, 0,0,0);
// imagecolortransparent($profImg, $bg);

imagealphablending($profImg, false);
imagesavealpha($profImg, true);
//imagecolortransparent($profImg, imagecolorallocatealpha($profImg, 0, 0, 0, 127));
// imagefilledrectangle($profImg, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);

imagecopyresampled($profImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

imagepng($profImg, $fileDesitin8n,0);
imagepng($srcImg, $file2Desitin8n,0);

}
```

any help would be appreciated.